# give space between particular <td> elements in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have two html table's inside a main table. I have to give the space between td of first table so that Heading one should be on top of Element1 and text box and Heading two should be on top of Element2 and select lists which are available in other table. Please suggest how can i achieve this, do i need to modify the html table structure.
Please find the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/x5tLdbz4/1/

Below is the css code:

```
td:nth-child(1) {
    padding-right: 90px;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<table>

 <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="hone" class="more-padding-on-right">
            Heading One
    </td>
    <td class="htwo">
           Heading Two
    </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
<table>
<tr valign="top">
<td>  Element1:<input id="myTest" type="text" value="">  </td>  
<td>
Element2:<SELECT id="one" size="10" multiple>
    <OPTION value="a">AAA</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="b">BB</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="c">CCC</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</td>
<td valign="center">
<a href="#">&gt;&gt;</a>
</td>
<td>
<SELECT id="two" size="10" multiple>
    <OPTION value="a">FF</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="b">GG</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="c">BHH</OPTION>

</SELECT>
</td>
</tr>
</table>    
</table>
```

Comment: You need to change the margin of one of the tables, i'd recommend that you checkout this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: Are you using tables to build page structure? Consider moving to divs. this will make easier to position and space items on the page

Comment: ok.can't we achieve this using tables?

Comment: why you use a few table?

Comment: why you are using this tables oriented structure?  is there any special reason ?
should you use div base structure?

Comment: Literally what you have asked for - https://jsfiddle.net/x5tLdbz4/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would merge the two tables into one, with `colspan` values.

Another correction, it should be `valign="middle"` not `center`.

http://jsfiddle.net/w8kvm0d9/

```css
.hone, .htwo {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
    font-size:12px;
    height:15px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
    border: 0;
    width: 80px;
}
td select {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="hone" class="more-padding-on-right">Heading One</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="htwo" colspan="3">Heading Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Element1:<input id="myTest" type="text" value=""/></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top">
            Element2:
            <SELECT id="one" size="10" multiple>
                <OPTION value="a">AAA</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="b">BB</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="c">CCC</OPTION>
            </SELECT>
        </td>
        <td valign="middle"><a href="#">&gt;&gt;</a></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <SELECT id="two" size="10" multiple>
                <OPTION value="a">FF</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="b">GG</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="c">BHH</OPTION>
            </SELECT>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way (if sticking with tables) is to use a single table for this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="hone" class="more-padding-on-right">Heading One</td>
        <td class="htwo">Heading Two</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="hthree">Heading Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>Element1:
            <input id="myTest" type="text" value="">
        </td>
        <td>Element2:
            <SELECT id="one" size="10" multiple>
                <OPTION value="a">AAA</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="b">BB</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="c">CCC</OPTION>
            </SELECT>
        </td>
        <td valign="center">
<a href="#">&gt;&gt;</a>

        </td>
        <td>
            <SELECT id="two" size="10" multiple>
                <OPTION value="a">FF</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="b">GG</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="c">BHH</OPTION>
            </SELECT>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rcj1xgur/3/

Comment: But you have removed the CSS for the heading background color, which when kept still problem remains the same , please check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rcj1xgur/2/ @James Wilkins.

Comment: If its tough achieving using html tables, can some one suggest using div tag. Thanks and appreciate your time.

Comment: I was going by the code you posted, which had `padding-right: 90px;`; I figured the rest was obvious.

Comment: Ok, I added the CSS.  This is not complicated. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting everything into a single table. When you have two separate tables but you want to the columns to align you'll find it nearly impossible to ensure that they always do (especially when a user resizes the browser window). You could also add <thead> and <tbody> tags to distinguish between the header rows and body rows. Also, since you've got 3 columns in the second table you'll need to use the `colspan` attribute for the second column of the header to tell it span 2 columns, thus allowing the columns to fit in (or, if I didn't understand the alignment you want you might need the `colspan` on the first header column instaed).

```
 <table>
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th class="hone" class="more-padding-on-right">
                 Heading One
             </th>
             <th class="htwo" colspan="2">
                 Heading Two
             </th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr valign="top">
             <td>  Element1:<input id="myTest" type="text" value="">  </td>  
             <td>
                 Element2:<SELECT id="one" size="10" multiple>
                     <OPTION value="a">AAA</OPTION>
                     <OPTION value="b">BB</OPTION>
                     <OPTION value="c">CCC</OPTION>
                 </SELECT>
             </td>
             <td valign="center">
                 <a href="#">&gt;&gt;</a>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <SELECT id="two" size="10" multiple>
                     <OPTION value="a">FF</OPTION>
                     <OPTION value="b">GG</OPTION>
                     <OPTION value="c">BHH</OPTION>
                 </SELECT>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use one table structure and it'll look something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/267/

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading 1</th>
            <th>Heading 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Element 1<input type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                Element 2
                <SELECT id="one" size="10" multiple>
                    <OPTION value="a">AAA</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="b">BB</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="c">CCC</OPTION>
                </SELECT>
                <a href="#" style="vertical-align: top;">&gt;&gt;</a>
                <SELECT id="two" size="10" multiple>
                    <OPTION value="a">FF</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="b">GG</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="c">BHH</OPTION> 
                </SELECT>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry to say, none of the solution mentioned here is not working when given the background color for the heading. Can someone suggest real solution. I can use div or html table. Thanks for all your suggestions.